# ¿que puedo hacer si me sale en este mensaje estoy utilizando Dreamweaver cs6 y wampserver?

Tags: wampserver, dreamweaver

[image: Necesito ayuda estoy realizando una pagina web con base de datos y estoy utilizando Dreamweaver y de servidor wampserver pero tengo el inconveniente de al mandarle a correr la pagina de administrador que tiene usuario y contraseña conectado con la base de datos me sale este error y no se como solucionarlo]

Necesito ayuda estoy realizando una pagina web con base de datos y estoy utilizando Dreamweaver y de servidor wampserver pero tengo el inconveniente de al mandarle a correr la pagina de administrador que tiene usuario y contraseña conectado con la base de datos me sale este error y no se como solucionarlo

Comment: Ahi dice traduccion literal, que la extension de mysql esta obsoleta, que puedes usar mysqli o PDO

Comment: Y como lo hago ??

Comment: supongo que en el panel de wamp puedes revisar si tienes una nueva version para poder actualizar, o en su defecto instala mysql independiente

Comment: Básicamente debes cambiar tus conexiones y consultas de mysql a mysqli

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y subes el contenido del archivo dda.php para darte mas luces